# printing conditionally with bash

Tags: string, bash, shell, scripting

I am trying to process a large number of text files. These text files contain either of the following two consecutive lines:

"_atom_site_fract_z" followed by "#END"

or

"_atom_site_fract_z" followed by strings such as "C1 C 0.46450 0.18880 0.92540"

I want to use bash/sed to only keep the files that are of the later type (files that does NOT have "_atom_site_fract_z" followed by "#END").

How do I achieve this?

NOTE: Two strings are separated by a NEWLINE. They are not separated by a space.

UPDATE: The name of files are stored in a text file, and I want to read the text file, line by line, to check if I should keep the file or not. I do not necessarily want to delete them, but want to save the files that are of later type in a separate folder within the directory.

UPDATE2: There are "other lines" besides these two lines. I want to search the file that has the particular combination of two lines. ALL files have both "_atom_site_frac_z" and "#END", but they don't appear immediately after one another. However, "_atom_site_frac_z" ALWAYS appear before "#END".

Comment: On separate lines or separated by a space on the same line?

Comment: separated by different line number. For example, if _atom_site_frac_z is line 9, #END will be line 10.

Comment: can each file contain both variants?

Comment: @jgr: no. each file contains only one of the variants.

Comment: so basically if one file contains the word "#END" it should be skipped?

Comment: @jgr: I've refined the question. Both files contain "#END".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you want to keep only *files* of the latter type. `sed` might be useful for dealing with lines, but for whole files you probably want `grep` with `find`.

```
find "$dir" -type f -exec grep -qF '_atom_site_fract_z#END' {} \; -print # get a list of the files to delete.
find "$dir" -type f -exec grep -qF '_atom_site_fract_z#END' {} \; -delete # actually delete them
```

**Update**

If your files are from a list in a *newline-separated* textfile then you can process them like this:

```
while read filename; do
    awk '!/#END/{
        checkNext=0;
    } /_atom_site_fract_z/{
        checkNext=1;
        next;
    } /#END/{
        if (checkNext) {
            print(FILENAME);
            exit(0);
        }
    }' "$filename"
done < list_of_files.txt
```

Comment: And you can use a regex to find the second type of files to print their names.

Comment: I don't understand this. what is $dir ?

Comment: NOTE: two strings are separated by a newline. they are not separated by a space.

Comment: @kojiro: what if I have a list of file names to search in a text file?

Comment: @Greg Even with the `find` solutions, you can change `-delete` to `-exec` and do something more appropriate such as moving the files. So I'm not going to change that part of the answer. But the `while` loop just prints out the names of the files that match so you can do whatever you like with them.

Comment: @kojiro: thanks! but it seems like the code does not do anything. it just runs but no output.

Comment: Nevermind! It runs, but I have to check the answers. will be back if the code works or not. Thanks for your help @kojiro!

Comment: @greg No, you're right, there was a bug in the awk script. Updated.

Comment: thanks @kojiro! actually I did something different but your answer gave me the most information to perform tasks that I wanted :-)

Answer (score 0):

In case the above doesn't work here is my sollution. Not exactly heavily tested, just so that you know.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read filename; do
   CHECK=""
   CHECK=$(awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n";RS=""} $1~/_atom_site_fract_z/ && $2~/#END/' $filename)
   if [ -z "$CHECK" ]; then
      echo $filename > new_files.txt
   fi
done < files.txt
```